# Get response from pending webservice with ajax

Tags: ajax

I have a web service which is executed with pending status in the browser , how can i get it's response because it did not go into succes function nor the error one.

Here is my code :

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: "https://domain_name/listenrealtime",
    data: {username: '', password:"" },
     headers: {},
     
     success: function (data) {
          console.log("success test");
          console.log(data);

            },
     error: function(data){
          console.log("error test");
           }

        })
```

here is a capture from the browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4TIb.png)

Comment: What does the URL "https://domain_name/listenrealtime" do with the username and password you send? Besides why are both variables empty strings?

Comment: Hi , username and password are hard coded inside my web service code , i publish the question with empty one because i can not share them on public.